# Only Jpg and Jpeg files are allowed

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I need to upload only .Jpg and .Jpeg files but while uploading it also allows .gif

Here is my file upload control with validation:

```
<td align="left" colspan="3">
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fuAttachment1" runat="server" />
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFile1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuAttachment1"
     Enabled="true" ErrorMessage="Invalid File. Please select valid file." ForeColor="Red"
    ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG)$">*
  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td> </tr>
```

Comment: Is writing `*` your way to be polite? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^.+\.(?:(?:[jJ][pP][eE][gG])|(?:[jJ][pP][gG]))$
```

More description

```
^           = beginning of string
.+          = at least one character (any character)
\.          = dot ('.')
(?:pattern) = match the pattern without storing the match)
[dD]        = any character in the set ('d' or 'D')
[xX]?       = any character in the set or none 
              ('x' may be missing so 'doc' or 'docx' are both accepted)
|           = either the previous or the next pattern
$           = end of matched string
```

You can also check [regex here](http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: Hey @Amith Agrawal.. now its working.... thank you very much :) evn nice explanation too